# How to catch wrong password/username response in angular?

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I’m trying to implement authentication in my angularjs app. 
I’ve read some articles about doing this properly. Here is one, for instance: https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec 
But I can’t realize how to make it respond on wrong username/password pair.
Let’s have a look at this code :

```
authService.login = function (credentials) {
return $http
    .post('/login', credentials)
    .then(function (res) {
        // populate user info
    }
);
```

};

I’ve tried to add here a second callback to “then” method and use “success”/”error” methods instead of “then” and I’ve tried to response on $http.post request with different error like 400 and 500 via status, but in any case all the errors are handled by the success method and callback.
What am I doing wrong? How to catch wrong password/username response in angular?

Comment: Just send HTTP status 401 from back-end when authentication fails, on angular the status code is next parameter after res in then callback(ex. function(res, status)) .

Comment: take a look at this generator https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

Comment: Thanks!
I’ve suddenly realized the cause of the problem. I had an $httpProvider’s custom interceptor from one example which returned rejection for any status except of 401.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually my own fault. My custom Intereptor simply swallowed authenticaion errors.